# Pynput on Python 2.7, or Pynput alternatives?

Tags: python-2.7, keyboard, arrow-keys

I want to learn how to make game bots, however am pretty sure Pynput only works with Python 3.5.

Does anyone have any conda packages or fixes for 2.7?

Are there any alternatives to Pynput with similar capabilities?

Cheers

Comment: try pygame module.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Pyautogui](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).  The documentation does not seem to mention 2.7 except on one line:

> On Linux, PyAutoGUI requires python-xlib (for Python 2) or python3-Xlib (for Python 3) module installed.

So it seems it is Python 2 compatible.